# Invalid transaction termination in procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, postgresql-13

We are running Postgres version 13.6.

I have a procedure that works fine when started directly (from PgAdmin) but fails when started from Python.
The goal is to add a row to the log with a start time and when the procedure finishes add an end time to that same row. We don't want the first logging to be rolled back when the procedure fails, so we added a commit in between.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stg.do_something()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
    proc_name character varying;

BEGIN
    BEGIN
    proc_name := 'stg.fill_prtm_configurationhierarchy';
    PERFORM mstr.log_procedure(proc_name, True::boolean);

    END;
COMMIT;

    BEGIN

    --Do some magic

    PERFORM mstr.log_procedure(proc_name, False::boolean);

    -- catch exception
        exception 
           when others THEN 
                RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;
                RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;
                PERFORM mstr.log_error(proc_name, SQLERRM);
    END;
END;
$BODY$;
```

When executed directly from a query window in pgAdmin, this works like a charm. If we make the procedure fail, we still have the log that shows us the procedure started, but never finished. When the procedure gets called from Python we get an error: "invalid transaction termination; Context PL/pgSQL at COMMIT."
If I call the procedure directly from within another procedure (also called from within pgAdmin), it works fine as long as I don't try to use dynamic SQL and/or the plain SQL EXECUTE command.

Can someone tell me the difference between calling from pgAdmin and Python, and how to resolve this?

From Python it is called by: "db.execute(cmd)"
where cmd is a string that holds: "CALL schema.procedure(parameters)" From Python it works fine when we disable the COMMIT.